# Subtract a year from a datetime column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a datetime column as below -

```
>>> df['ACC_DATE'].head(2)
538   2006-04-07
550   2006-04-12
Name: ACC_DATE, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Now, I want to subtract an year from each row of this column. How can I achieve the same & which library can I use?

The expected field -

```
        ACC_DATE    NEW_DATE
538   2006-04-07  2005-04-07
549   2006-04-12  2005-04-12
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can use [`DateOffset`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html?highlight=dateoffset#dateoffset-objects) to achieve this:

```
In[88]:
df['NEW_DATE'] = df['ACC_DATE'] - pd.DateOffset(years=1)
df

Out[88]: 
        ACC_DATE   NEW_DATE
index                      
538   2006-04-07 2005-04-07
550   2006-04-12 2005-04-12
```

Comment: I'm curious, what does it do when your starting date is Feb. 29?

Comment: @MarkRansom good question I just tried this, for `2004-02-29` subtracting a year becomes `2003-02-28`

Comment: If the user wants the start date of a one year period, subtracting `pd.DateOffset(years=1, days=-1)` may be more accurate.

Answer (score 18):

Use [DateOffset](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects):

```
df["NEW_DATE"] = df["ACC_DATE"] - pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)
print (df)
        ACC_DATE   NEW_DATE
index                      
538   2006-04-07 2005-04-07
550   2006-04-12 2005-04-12
```

Comment: May i ask what's the difference between `pd.DateOffset(years=1)` and yours `pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)`?

Comment: @ahbon if use `plural years` added 1 year, if use `singular year` set to year `1`

Comment: `pd.DateOffset` also worked: `pd.Timestamp.today() - pd.DateOffset(years=2)`

Answer (score 15):

You could use pd.Timedelta:

```
df["NEW_DATE"] = df["ACC_DATE"] - pd.Timedelta(days=365)
```

Or replace:

```
df["NEW_DATE"] = df["ACC_DATE"].apply(lambda x: x.replace(year=x.year - 1))
```

But neither will catch leap years so you could use `dateutil.relativedelta` :

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import  relativedelta

df["NEW_DATE"] = df["ACC_DATE"].apply(lambda x: x - relativedelta(years=1))
```

Comment: this also works with `mypy` (opposed to `pd.DateOffset`)

Answer (score 0):

If having a **single [**`pd.Timestamp`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) object** rather than a column,

1. Using `pd.DateOffset(years=n)` is not ideal as it produces:

> UserWarning: Discarding nonzero nanoseconds in conversion

2. `pd.Timedelta()` doesn't accept years.

The only approach that worked for me in this case is [**`pd.Timestamp.replace`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.replace.html):

```
t = pd.Timestamp.now()
t = t.replace(year=t.year - n)
```

This was hinted at in the [answer by Padriac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31169977/) but it needed further clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html#pandas.Timedelta) with strings:

```
df['col'] - pd.Timedelta('365 days')
```

or

```
df['col'] + pd.Timedelta('-365 days')
```