# How to group every date in an uneven pandas datetime series with the closest date 1 year ago in the same series?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I processing time-series data within a pandas dataframe. The datetime index is incomplete (i.e. some dates are missing).

I want to create a new column with a datetime series of 1 year offset, but only containg dates present in the original datetimeindex . The challenge is that the exact 1y match is not present in the index in many cases.

```
Index (Input)   1 year offset (Output)
1/2/2014        None
1/3/2014        None
1/6/2014        None
1/7/2014        None
1/9/2014        None
1/10/2014       None
1/2/2015        1/2/2014
1/5/2015        1/3/2014
1/6/2015        1/6/2014
1/7/2015        1/7/2014
1/8/2015        1/9/2014
1/9/2015        1/10/2014
```

**The requirements are as follows**:

1. Every date as of 1/2/2015 must have a corresponding offset date (no blanks)
2. Every date within the "offset date" group must also be present in the Index column (i.e. introduction of new dates, like 1/8/2014, is not desired
3. All offset dates must be ordered in an ascending way (the sequence of dates must be preserved)

**What I have tried so far**:

1. The [Dateoffset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169774/subtract-an-year-from-a-datetime-column-in-pandas) doesn't help, since it is insensitive to dates not present in the index.
2. The [.shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982089/how-to-shift-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe) method `data["1 year offset (Output)"] = data.Index.shift(365)` doesn't help because the number of dates within the index is different across the years.

**What I am trying to do now has several steps**:

1. Apply [Dateoffset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169774/subtract-an-year-from-a-datetime-column-in-pandas) method at first to create "temp 1 year offset"
2. Remove single dates from "temp 1 year offset" that are not present in datetimeindex using `set(list)` method and replace cells by NaN
3. Select dates in datetimeindex whose "temp 1 year offset" is NaN and substract one year
4. Map the Dates from (3) to its closest date in the datetimeindex using  `argmin`

The challenge here is that I am getting double entries as well as a descending order of days in some cases. Those mess up with the results in the following way (see the timedeltas between day n and day n+1):

```
Index (Input)   1 year offset (Output) Timedelta
4/17/2014       4/16/2014              1
4/22/2014       4/17/2014              1
4/23/2014       4/25/2014              8
4/24/2014       None
4/25/2014       4/22/2014             -3
4/28/2014       4/23/2014              1
4/29/2014       4/24/2014              1
4/30/2014       4/25/2014              1
```

In any case, this last approach seems to be an overkill concerning the simplicity of the underlying goal. Is there a faster and more simple way to do it?

**How to group every date in an uneven pandas datetime series with the closest date one year ago in the same series?**

Comment: many thanks for your answer - list comprehension is new to me - could you be a bit less minimalist?

Answer (score 1):

This would be a way:

However look at this thread to properly handle 1 year when the year has 366 days:
[Add one year in current date PYTHON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741618/add-one-year-in-current-date-python)

This code therefore needs some small modifications.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(dates=[
 '1/3/2014',
 '1/6/2014',
 '1/7/2014',
 '1/9/2014',
 '1/10/2014',
 '1/2/2015',
 '1/5/2015',
 '1/6/2015',
 '1/7/2015',
 '1/8/2015',
 '1/9/2015']))

# Convert column to datetime
df.dates = pd.to_datetime(df.dates)

# Store min(year) as a variable
minyear = min(df.dates).year

# Calculate the day with timedelta -365 days (might fail on 2012?)
df['offset'] = [(i + datetime.timedelta(days=-365)).date()
                if i.year != minyear else None for i in df.dates]

df
```

Returns:

```
        dates      offset
0  2014-01-03        None
1  2014-01-06        None
2  2014-01-07        None
3  2014-01-09        None
4  2014-01-10        None
5  2015-01-02  2014-01-02
6  2015-01-05  2014-01-05
7  2015-01-06  2014-01-06
8  2015-01-07  2014-01-07
9  2015-01-08  2014-01-08
10 2015-01-09  2014-01-09
```

Comment: +1 for elucidating your approach. This doesnt solve the issue. In your above example, the "offset"-column2 output contains 6 dates. But only 3 of those dates are also present in column1. I need something which only chooses an offset date for column2 among the complete group of dates present in column 1. Sorry for my lack of precision, I adjust the question accordingly.

Comment: @sudonym yep that makes things more complicated. Unfortunately I need to work on smh else for the time being and can’t help you further atm.

Comment: Reading your question carefully again my answer makes no sense :/