# How to subtract number of years from a date in python?

Tags: python, pandas, time

## Data

I have the following data:

```
data = [['1987-09-01', 5], ['1987-09-01', 2.66], ['1987-09-01', np.nan]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'year'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

## Goal

To subtract the number of years from the date. For np.nan, I do not want any value to be subtracted.

## Attempt

My attempt is as follows:

```
df['Date'] - pd.to_timedelta(df.year.astype(str), units = 'Y')
```

Which leads to the following error:

```
ValueError: no units specified
```

I know that the number of years is not supported in pd.to_timedelta. I was wondering how I can accomplish my goal in another way?

Comment: Think you could probably do (untested): `df['Date'] - pd.to_timedelta(df.year.fillna(0), unit='y')` ? (note that it's `unit` (singular) - not plural)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subtract an year from a datetime column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169774/subtract-an-year-from-a-datetime-column-in-pandas)

Comment: `Y` and `M` are being deprecated because they do not represent a fixed amount of time. To achieve what you want, you should consider what a year represent to you.
 - If, in your understanding, "a year" means "365 days", just multiply your delta by 365 and use `day` as unit (in this case, you may want to use 1 year = 365.25 days, to consider leap years).
 - If 1 year variation means the same day in the next/previous year, just add/subtract the integer part of the delta from the year field and decide how to use the remaining decimal part of the delta (ask yourself what 0.66 of a year means).

Comment: However, although `Y` is deprecated, it still works, as @JonClements said.

Answer (score 2):

`pd.DateOffset` should work for you

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Date'] = df['Date'] - pd.DateOffset(years=1)
```